# Using OpenGL to write to an image file

Tags: c++, image, opengl, graphics

I'm just curious if there is a way to use OpenGL to write pixel data to an external JPEG/PNG/some other image file type (and also create an image to write the data to if one does not already exist). I couldn't really find anything on the subject. My program doesn't really make use of openGL at all otherwise, I just need something that can write out images.

Comment: I don't think OpenGL can do this on its own. But you can check out DevIL/OpenIL, it's a library that makes writing images to file easy.

Comment: Do you have any further questions regarding the existing answers or did you solve this problem yourself already?

Comment: Would instructions for doing so on iOS devices help get you started? If so: https://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/11/tech-serious-ios-developers-use-every.html

Answer (score 5):

Every image "put into" or "taken from" OpenGL is in a rather raw pixel format. OpenGL does neither have functionality for file I/O nor for handling of sophisticated image formats like e.g. BMP, JPEG or PNG, as that is completely out of its scope. So you will have to look for a different library to manage that and if this was the only reason you considered OpenGL, then you don't need it at all.

A very simple and easy to use one (and with an interface similar to OpenGL) would be [*DevIL*](http://openil.sourceforge.net/). But many other larger frameworks for more complex tasks, like *Qt* (GUI and OS) or *OpenCV* (image processing) have functionality for image loading and saving. And last but not least many of the individual formats, like JPEG or PNG usually also have small official open-source libraries for handling their respective files.

Comment: This starts off accurate, but gets a little fuzzy towards the end; this is what it looks like to do so on iOS (you'll see what I mean if you delve into it a little bit): https://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/11/tech-serious-ios-developers-use-every.html